# Why does Iconv work different in irb and the Ruby interpreter?

Tags: ruby, irb, iconv

I have to convert Latin chars like `éáéíóúÀÉÍÓÚ` etc., into a string to similar ones without special accents or wired symbols:

```
é -> e
è -> e
Ä -> A
```

I have a file named "test.rb":

```
require 'iconv'

puts Iconv.iconv("ASCII//translit", "utf-8", 'è').join
```

When I paste those lines into irb it works, returning "e" as expected.

Running:

```
$ ruby test.rb
```

I get "`?`" as output.

I'm using irb 0.9.5(05/04/13) and Ruby 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352) [i386-linux].

Comment: yes, is encoded as utf-8. It also the default system encoding.
I think also it couldn't work because, if i had good memory, the "#encoding" magic-comment was introduce in 1.9.

although i've just tried and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ruby 1.8.7 was not multibyte character savvy like 1.9+ is. In general, it treats a string as a series of bytes, rather than characters. If you need better handling of such characters, consider upgrading to 1.9+.

James Gray has a [series of articles](http://blog.grayproductions.net/categories/character_encodings) about dealing with multibyte characters in Ruby 1.8. I highly recommend taking the time to read through them. It's a complex subject so you'll want to read the entire series he wrote a couple times.

Also, 1.8 encoding support needs the `$KCODE` flag set:

```
$KCODE = "U"
```

so you'll need to add that to code running in 1.8.

Here is a bit of sample code:

```
#encoding: UTF-8

require 'rubygems'
require 'iconv'

chars = "éáéíóúÀÉÍÓÚ"

puts Iconv.iconv("ASCII//translit", "utf-8", chars)

puts chars.split('')
puts chars.split('').join
```

Using ruby 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352) [x86_64-darwin10.7.0] and running it in IRB, I get:

```
1.8.7 :001 > #encoding: UTF-8
1.8.7 :002 >   
1.8.7 :003 >   require 'iconv'
true
1.8.7 :004 > 
1.8.7 :005 >   chars = "\303\251\303\241\303\251\303\255\303\263\303\272\303\200\303\211\303\215\303\223\303\232"
"\303\251\303\241\303\251\303\255\303\263\303\272\303\200\303\211\303\215\303\223\303\232"
1.8.7 :006 > 
1.8.7 :007 >   puts Iconv.iconv("ASCII//translit", "utf-8", chars)
'e'a'e'i'o'u`A'E'I'O'U
nil
1.8.7 :008 > 
1.8.7 :009 >   puts chars.split('')
?
?
?
?
?
?
?
?
?
?
?
?
?
?
?
?
?
?
?
?
?
?
nil
1.8.7 :010 > puts chars.split('').join
éáéíóúÀÉÍÓÚ
```

At line 9 in the output I told Ruby to split the line into its concept of characters, which in 1.8.7, was bytes. The resulting '?' mean it didn't know what to do with the output. A line 10 I told it to split, which resulted in an array of bytes, which `join` then reassembled into the normal string, allowing the multibyte characters to be translated normally.

Running the same code using Ruby 1.9.2 shows better, and more expected and desirable, behavior:

```
1.9.2p290 :001 > #encoding: UTF-8
1.9.2p290 :002 >   
1.9.2p290 :003 >   require 'iconv'
true
1.9.2p290 :004 > 
1.9.2p290 :005 >   chars = "éáéíóúÀÉÍÓÚ"
"éáéíóúÀÉÍÓÚ"
1.9.2p290 :006 > 
1.9.2p290 :007 >   puts Iconv.iconv("ASCII//translit", "utf-8", chars)
'e'a'e'i'o'u`A'E'I'O'U
nil
1.9.2p290 :008 > 
1.9.2p290 :009 >   puts chars.split('')
é
á
é
í
ó
ú
À
É
Í
Ó
Ú
nil
1.9.2p290 :010 > puts chars.split('').join
éáéíóúÀÉÍÓÚ
```

Ruby maintained the multibyte-ness of the characters, through the `split('')`.

Notice that in both cases, `Iconv.iconv` did the right thing, it created characters that were visually similar to the input characters. While the leading apostrophe looks out of place, it's there as a reminder the characters were accented originally.

For more information, see the links on the right to related questions or try [this SO search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby+iconv) for `[ruby] [iconv]`

Comment: Ok thank you so much, i understand a bit more! Now I have 2 problems: first i can't upgrade version 'cause the software *must* work also on 1.8.7, the second is in the title: if i run your script using `ruby` (instead of IRB) the output differs and seems that Iconv doesn't works in this case.

Comment: And also my output for the 7th line is different: i have `eaeiouAEIOU` instead your `'e'a'e'i'o'u\`A'E'I'O'U`.

Comment: Ruby 1.9+ automatically does a `require 'rubygems'`, so you'll need to add that to your script with 1.8.7. I'll add it to my sample to reduce confusion.

Comment: @user1089668, check out the link to James Gray's articles I added to the example also.

Comment: i spent a lot of time to solve the problem: i convinced my boss to upgrade ruby! =)